# CSS - Styling table

Tags: html, css

i need to make something like this:
[image]

I am not 100% sure how to make this so i decide for table which can be usefull,  but it just terrible scatter what i did, my try looks like:

```
    <table>
      <tr>
          <td rowspan="2" class="img-position"><a href="#"><img src="images/foto.png"></a></td>
          <td class="topic-name"><a href="#">Název topicu nebo článku </a></td>
          <td class="date">28.8.2014 / 19:30</td>
      </tr>
    </table>
```

My CSS:

```
#sub-content .left{
    width: 326px;
    height: 145px;
    display: inline-block;
    float:left;        
}

#sub-content img{
    width: 122px;
    height: 121px;
    display: inline-block;
    margin-top: 0px;
    margin-left: 5px;        
}

#sub-content .topic-name{
    width: 150px;
    height: 14px;
    line-height 14px;
    margin-bottom: 130px;
    margin-left: 10px;
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: top;
    text-decoration: underline;
    font-weight: 14px;         
}

#sub-content table{
    width:326px;
    height:145px;         
}

#sub-content tr{
    margin: 10px 0px 0px 0px;
    padding: 0px;
    height: 36px;         
}

#sub-content .date{            
}

#sub-content .img-position{
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
    width: 122px;
    height: 121px;
    display: inline-block;         
}
```

And i cant move from my position to style atleast one of that part and then just copy it 3 times. I hope i find somebody here who can help me to fix it.

Live preview can be found on: http://funedit.com/andurit/try1/

Thanks for reading my post

Comment: In order to make sth like this you have to work out a lot at gym...

Comment: So recomand me how should i do that: )

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all I recommend you to read this : [Why not use tables for layout in HTML?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/83073/why-not-use-tables-for-layout-in-html) its about how you should not create your layout.

I prepared you basic jsfiddle example with your given stuff to make you catch up on things faster. Check this out. [Example layout](http://jsfiddle.net/sLcK9/1/)

I changed your given layout to divs and spans and it would look more or less like this:

```
<div class='article-container'>
  <div class='article'>  
  <div class="img-position">
    <a href="#"><img src="http://funedit.com/andurit/try1/images/foto.png"/></a> 
  </div>
  <span class="topic-name"><a href="#">Název topicu nebo článku </a></span>
  <span class="date">28.8.2014 / 19:30</span>
  </div>
  .
  . 
  .
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Doing this in tables NON Semantic and I not recommend it. 
For my opinion you need to use this structure

**Html**

```
<div class="block1">block1</div>
        <div class="block2">block2</div>
        <div class="block3">block3</div>
    </div>
* {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
html, body {
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
}
.wrapper{
    width: 100%;
    background: #ddd;
}
.block1{
    float: left;
    width: 33.3%;
    background: #c01;
    height: 200px;
    margin-right: 1px;
}
.block2{
    float: left;
    width: 33.3%;
    background: #c01;
    height: 200px;
    margin-right: 1px;
}
.block3{
    float: left;
    width: 33.3%;
    background: #c01;
    height: 200px;
}
```

Comment: this is the case carried using tables does not work the desired effect is achieved

Answer (score 0):

Use [bootstrap](http://getbootstrap.com/) grids, to achieve tabular style. It's responsive and easy to implement.
Include this [CSS file](http://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.1.1/css/bootstrap.min.css).

```
<div class='row'>
       <div class='col-xs-4 tab'> <!-- 1/3rd size of the parent container -->
        <div class='row'>
          <!-- Image box -->
          <div class='col-xs-4'> 
            <a href="#"><img src="images/foto.png"></a> 
          </div>
          <!-- Description box -->
          <div class='col-xs-8'> <!-- 2/3rd size of parent container -->
           <div><a href="#">Název topicu nebo článku </a></div>
           <div>28.8.2014 / 19:30</div>
           <div>Lorem Ipsum</div>
         </div>
       </div>
     </div>

   <div class='col-xs-4 tab'> <!-- 1/3rd size of the parent container -->
    <div class='row'>
      <!-- Image box -->
      <!-- ...  Follow same structure as above-->
   </div>
  </div>

   <div class='col-xs-4 tab'> <!-- 1/3rd size of the parent container -->
    <div class='row'>
      <!-- ... Follow same structure as above -->
   </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

This will give you 3 columns, in a row of equal width. 
For fixed height of each tab, just provide

```
<style>
.tab{
  height: 200px;
}
</style>
```

For implementation details, See [here](http://jsbin.com/fiwos/1/edit).